# ActionBarSherlock height attributes in low sdk

Tags: android, themes, height, actionbarsherlock

I'm getting a little bit crazy with this issue. I created an amount of themes and read almost every topic about this subject.

In the last time i created a theme with action bar style generator and imported to my project but no luck either. The Problems is that in older sdk versions lower then 4.0 i can't seem to define my sherlock action bar size.

I have this:

```
<style name="final_solid_ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_final</item>
    <item name="height">48dip</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_final</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_final</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/final_ProgressBar</item>

    <item name="android:height">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_final</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_final</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_final</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/final_ProgressBar</item>
</style>
```

but keeps getting me several errors of theme configuration like style contains key with bad entry and nothing happens to the bar size. Please could anyone help me with that, i'm going crazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the size of the action bar, set `android:actionBarSize` item in the theme:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item>
</style>
```

Note that the default action bar sizes are different for portrait (48dp), landscape (40dp) and sw600dp (56dp) configurations.